# cameraPose() not working properly in Matlab R2015b

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

When using cameraPose(), sometimes correct poses cannot be calculated. I created simulated camera data and compared with the cameraPose() output. I found inside cameraPose(), the correct pose is calculated as one of the four possible solutions, but somehow is not chosen. I suspect this is a bug:

Line 192 in cameraPose.m, it should be:
m2 = bsxfun(@plus, m1, Ts(i, :)*Rs(:,:,i)) * Rs(:,:,i)';

instead of:
m2 = bsxfun(@minus, m1, Ts(i, :)) * Rs(:,:,i)';

Because m1 is in the coordinate frame of camera 1, but Ts(i, :) is the translation from the origin of camera 2 to the origin of camera 1 in the coordinate frame of camera 2. So we need to inverse it first.

Can anybody confirm on this?

BTW, the convention of right multiplication for rotation matrix really sucks...

Comment: Would it be better to send this to mathworks? Alternatively, you might like to phrase it as a question that can be answered by people.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I rephrased it a little bit, is this OK? Just want to share this with other people who are also struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a bug, which was fixed in R2016a.  See the [Mathworks Bug Report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1309898).